# esc_url() and Wordpress Security?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can someone explain when to use escaping functions?

My goal is to secure my Wordpress theme. I used a blank theme by Chris Coyier and added code to make the website I wanted. I noticed other themes used escaping functions but not Coyier's blank theme so I want to understand where to insert these.

After reading Codex and google results and researching the code of a few themes, I am still unclear on when to use

```
esc_url()  
esc_attr()  
esc_html()
```

I do not see a pattern of when to use these. For example, in one theme, for home_url ( '/' ) -- notice that esc_url is used in header.php but not in searchform.php -- Why?

header.php

```
<a href=
// NOTICE ESCAPING FUNCTION BELOW
"<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"
title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
```

searchform.php

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action=
// NO ESCAPING FUNCTION BELOW
"<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>"
>
```

Comment: Here is an example of when to use `esc_url` instead of `esc_attr` to prevent XSS: `<a href="<?= esc_url('javascript:alert(1)') ?>">test</a>`. If you would have used `esc_attr`, JavaScript code would still be executed.

Answer (score 7):

The escape functions serve to protect against attacks and weird characters. Some of the things the functions do is remove invalid characters, remove dangerous characters, and encode characters as HTML entities.

The problem is that untrusted data comes from not just users, but could come from things saved in your own database.

As a general rule, it is good to use the escape functions when any part of the URL is not generated by Wordpress functions. If the entire URL is generated only by Wordpress functions then the escape functions are not necessary.

For example, if you wanted to print the URL and add a query string like this

```
<?php echo get_permalink() . '?order=time' ?>
```

you should be in the habit of using an escape function because you typed some of the actual URL.

```
<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink() . '?order=time') ?>
```

Still, it would be better to use the *add_query_string* function like this

```
<?php echo add_query_arg('order', 'time', get_permalink()) ?>
```

In this second example, you would not need an escape function because the URL is generated entirely by Wordpress functions.

In your example in the question, the escape function is not necessary in the *header.php* file. The person who wrote that code was probably just in the habit of doing it and it is ok to put there even when it is not needed.

A good place to start reading about data validation would be on the Wordpress codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the wordpress escape function for any user inserted content, not **necesary** for wordpress function. But in plugins, template, forms or stuff like this you need to use the escape functions.

Comment: John, can you clarify..... 1. By user inserted content, do you mean a Search Form, Contact Form, and Newsletter sign up? ..... 2. In my example regarding home_url ( '/' ) can you explain why esc_url() is used in header.php and not in searchform.php? These php files are within the same theme.

Comment: in searchform.php isn't used because is not necesarry and in header because they used to escape anything I guess

Comment: But isn't searchform considered "user inserted" content? Thus you would use esc_url () ...correct?

Comment: yes, but if you are carefully you can see that the generated link is for the "action" atribute, so isn't necesary to escape that url....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the wordpress escape functions for any user insert content as John says ..

Have a look at the link i provided to know about  wordpress escape functions..

http://codeseekah.com/2012/03/13/wordpress-escape-functions/

Comment: Answers consisting only or mainly of links are discouraged, as the content of the remote site may change or disappear, and readers have to click the link to see if it is useful. The recommended approach is to summaries the main points in the answer itself, and include the link as "further reading".