# Purpose of using esc_url

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't understand why we need to use the `esc_url` if I myself am the one who actually wrote the URL like:

`echo get_template_directory_url . '/someText'`

Although the `/someText` is hardcoded but I know it's clean and safe because I wrote it. What are the circumstances that this will be unsafe (like how do bad guys do bad things when I don't use the `esc_url` in this case? Do they hack into the server? If they can really hack into the server, they won't even bother the `esc_url` already?

I have referred to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30583251/19507498 , but he just explain how we use it without explaining why we need it.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this function is to replace spaces and special characters with their encoded url pendants. For example   will be replace with `%20`. This is needed, because spaces and some other special characters like umlauts or `ß` are not allowed in urls.

EDIT:
Furthermore `?` and `&` need to be encoded, because those have special meanings in urls.